# Writing unit tests against PrintfFormat

Tags: f#

I have a type that I'm trying to understand by writing unit tests against it, however I can't reason what to do with PrintfFormat

```
  type ValueFormat<'p,'st,'rd,'rl,'t,'a> = {
      format: PrintfFormat<'p,'st,'rd,'rl,'t>
      paramNames: (string list) option
      handler: 't -> 'a
    }
    with 
      static member inline construct (this: ValueFormat<_,_,_,_,_,_>) =
        let parser s = 
          s |> tryKsscanf this.format this.handler
            |> function Ok x -> Some x | _ -> None
        let defaultNames =
            this.format.GetFormatterNames() 
              |> List.map (String.replace ' ' '_' >> String.toUpperInvariant)
              |> List.map (sprintf "%s_VALUE")
        let names = (this.paramNames ?| defaultNames) |> List.map (sprintf "<%s>")
        let formatTokens = this.format.PrettyTokenize names
        (parser, formatTokens)
```

I feel confident that I can figure everything out but PrintfFormat is throwing me with all those generics.

The file I'm looking at for the code I want to unit test is [here for the FSharp.Commandline framework](https://github.com/cannorin/FSharp.CommandLine/blob/master/src/FSharp.CommandLine/optionValues.fs).

My question is, what is PrintfFormat and how should it be used?

A link to the printf.fs file is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/main/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs#L35-35). It contains the definition of PrintfFormat

Comment: I originally had 2 questions but someone voted to close because I had two questions. I took out the second question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PrintfFormat<'Printer,'State,'Residue,'Result,'Tuple>` type, as [defined in the F# source code](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/ec5bad3a391357e03ff2286a264f0e4faf7d840d/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fsi#L54), has four type parameters:

- `'Result` is the type that your formatting/parsing function produces. This is `string` for `sprintf`
- `'Printer` is a type of a function generated based on the format string, e.g. `"%d and %s"` will give you a function type `int -> string -> 'Result`
- `'Tuple` is a tuple type generated based on the format string, e.g. `"%d and %s"` will give you a tuple type `int * string`.
- `'State` and `'Residue` are type parameters that are used when you have a custom formatter using `%a`, but I'll ignore that for now for simplicity (it's never needed unless you have `%a` format string)

There are two ways of using the type. Either for formatting, in which case you'll want to write a function that returns `'Printer` as the result. The hard thing about this is that you need to construct the return function using reflection. Here is an example that works only with one format string:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let myformat (fmt:PrintfFormat<'Printer,obj,obj,string,'Tuple>) : 'Printer = 
  unbox <| FSharpValue.MakeFunction(typeof<'Printer>, fun o ->
    box (o.ToString()) )
  
myformat "%d" 1
myformat "%s" "Yo"
```

This simply returns the parameter passed as a value for `%d` or `%s`. To make this work for multiple arguments, you'd need to construct the function recursively (so that it's not just e.g. `int -> string` but also `int -> (int -> string)`)

In the other use, you define a function that returns `'Tuple` and it needs to create a tuple containing values according to the specified formatting string. Here is a small sample that only handles `%s` and `%d` format strings:

```
open FSharp.Reflection

let myscan (fmt:PrintfFormat<'Printer,obj,obj,string,'Tuple>) : 'Tuple = 
  let args = 
    fmt.Value 
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.choose (function
      | '%', 'd' -> Some(box 123)
      | '%', 's' -> Some(box "yo")
      | _ -> None)
  unbox <| FSharpValue.MakeTuple(Seq.toArray args, typeof<'Tuple>)
  
myscan "%d %s %d"
```

Comment: Perfect! Now I'm curious how that string gets converted to type PrintfFormat. Anyways, this is good enough to unblock me so I can continue my unit testing and understanding of the original project I set out to learn. Thank you for giving your time to answer my question!

Comment: The format string gets turned to `PrintfFormat` by some _magic_ in the F# compiler :-)